# SAS University Edition - local host 10080 really long time initalizing

Tags: sas

I am trying to use the SAS University Edition for the first time. I followed the instructions given from the download page, using Linux Ubuntu and VirtualBox. Everything worked fine, I started the virtual machine and then opened Localhost 10080 in Mozilla Firefox 77.0.1 for Ubuntu. The thing is SAS studio takes really long time initializing - haven't gotten passed the Initializing state after 10 minutes, that can't be normal?

UPDATE: Partially solved, could load SAS University Edition in Chrome. Still, a mystery to me why I couldn't use Firefox.

Comment: try again but disable all plugins - if works then enable one by one until you find the offending one. Load of work when you can use Chrome though

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have adequate RAM atleast 3GB is good. Do not put numerous plugin in the browser. If possible, download a fresh browser and use it only for that purpose. I have also faced the issue.